# Connecting to the ftp server on android gives issue

Tags: android, python, ftp

I have the android FTPserver app running on my android mobile under Tethering mode. I connected to my mobiles network from my laptop and tried to connect to mobile via FTP to access few files. I wrote a python code that uses the ftp connection to transfer files but I am unable to perform simple connection.

I keep getting this error

in windows:

```
server.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getadderinfo failed
```

in linux:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

I searched so many places but never found a proper solution. All I could findout was people suggesting to check the firewall. I checked the firewall settings and everything and still I get the problem.

When I use a client software (filezilla) it does get connected.

I am a newbie to python could someone possibly tell me where I am going wrong?

here is my simple connecting code:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP("192.168.43.1,5002")
ftp.login("usrid","pwd")
```

I am unable to connect to a general ftp test site, Here is the code for that:

```
from ftplib import FTP

ftp = FTP('ftp.cwi.nl')
ftp.login("anonymous","anonymous@")
ftp.retrlines('LIST')
```

Comment: its pretty urgent can some on help me out??

Comment: Why doesnt any one answer my question???

Answer (score 0):

do this:

> ftp = FTP()
> ftp.connect("192.168.43.1", 5002)

instead of:

> ftp = FTP("192.168.43.1,5002")

because you can't give non-standard port number to the constructor.

Code:

```
from ftplib import FTP
    
ftp = FTP()

ftp.connect("192.168.43.1", 5002)
ftp.login("usrid", "pwd")
ftp.dir()

ftp.close()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32476806)